# German Work Visa Questions

Tags: working-visas, germany

I have an interview at the German Embassy for a work visa, next month. While I was going through list of questions that the officer asks during the interview. I found that some officers also asked whether I have resigned from the current job or not.

The resignation letter from the current employer is not among their checklist.

Also, how can I resign without knowing, what are the chances of me getting a visa. Just 0.1% case if a visa is not issued then I'll lose both the jobs.

In this case, how to handle this question?

The notice period is 2 months and joining is in Feb 2020.

Answer (score 4):

> I found that some officers also asked whether I have resigned from the current job or not.
>
> ...
>
> how to handle this question?

Tell the truth.  If you haven't resigned from the job, say so.  Say that whether you resign or not is contingent on your getting the visa.  If there are other conditions that must be met before you will resign from the job, mention them.

From your edit and comments, it is apparent that you have a two-month notice period, that you hope to start your new job less than two months after finishing your old job, and that you will use accrued leave to enable this.  If the visa officer asks about that, just say so.  There is nothing wrong with doing that.

The one thing you should be most careful about is allowing the visa officer to suspect you of being deceptive.  If you do that, it is very likely that you visa will be refused.  The best way to avoid this suspicion is to *tell the truth.*

Comment: Wouldn't officer say that if you haven't resigned yet, how would you manage to join within the notice period of 2 months? Joining date is in Feb 2020

Comment: @paul perhaps.  Is your notice period in fact 2 months?  Many people have no notice period at all, so if you have a notice period, you should include it in the question.

Comment: Added! Will your answer remain the same or there is a different way to respond now?

Comment: @paul how do you in fact plan to handle the two-month notice period if the visa is granted?

Comment: I will adjust the leaves within my notice period this is somehow manageable. But it's reverse "Where would I work if I don't get visa and resign from current job also?" is more tricky. What do you suggest?

Comment: @paul I suggest telling the truth.  If they ask about your notice period say that you'll use your leave to make it work.

Comment: @paul What is your prospective employer’s expectation? Is the joining date of Feb 2020 fixed? It’s extremely common for employers to accept some slippage when new employees need to give notice to their existing employer but don’t want to do so until all the formalities regarding their new job are complete.

Comment: @Traveller, you made a strong, genuine point. But the question is, what should be my response to the officer?

Comment: @Traveller, sorry I missed answering your question. Yes, the future employer is flexible with joining dates.

Comment: @paul I think you’re over-thinking this. As Phoog says - tell the truth. You don’t want to resign until you’re certain of being able to take up your new job, and once your visa is approved you will use your saved leave to reduce the notice period and liaise with your new employer to agree a final starting date. It’s utterly normal - I’ve had many new employees do exactly that over the years.

Answer (score 1):

During all of my research on the German work visa, I have never heard of anyone being refused for not having a resignation letter. It's not an official requirement, and it's not listed anywhere in the official resources. I was never asked this question, even though I applied for this visa twice.

Comment: Why it got rejected earlier in the first attempt?

Comment: It can be rejected for a variety of reasons. There is a lot of variation in the process, depending on who interviews you and processes your case.

Comment: Per forums available on the internet, all I know is that there are negligible chances of rejection if you have the job offer. Could you please share a few reasons from your personal experience. It would help in my case.